# Exception from Deps recompute function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'option1' of undefined

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have a page which is rendering fine and whenever i refresh the page it is showing exception
like below

```
Exception from Deps recompute function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'option1' of undefined
    at Object.Template.display_poll.helpers.product_title1 (http://localhost:3000/client/xxx.js?9b4f281e748352d5500dbda34a33f155fc8cc293:838:49)
    at apply (http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:276:24)
    at invoke (http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:301:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:365:30
    at Object.Spark.labelBranch (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:1170:14)
    at branch (http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:355:20)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:364:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156:11)
    at template (http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:358:7)
```

the exception causing line is

```js
product_title1:function() {
    var title1=Polls_Coll.findOne({_id:this._id}).option1[0].pd;
    return  title1;
}
```

Here is my template

```html
<template name="display_poll">
  <!-- displaying poll question -->
  {{uniqueid}}
  <p class="label-design table-pop-more" name="{{unique_id}}">
    <img src="/images/polls.jpg">{{question}}</p>
  <div class="table-pop-more">
    <div class="poll-options" id="menuitems">
      <ul>
        <!-- product thumbnails -->
        <li><input type="text" class="pad-top" id="{{id_op1}}"  
                   value="{{product_title1}}" readonly/><br></li>
        <li><input type="text" class="pad-top" id="{{id_op2}}"  
                   value="{{product_title2}}" readonly/><br></li>
        <li><input type="text" class="pad-top" id="{{id_op3}}"  
                   value="{{product_title3}}" readonly/><br></li>
        <li><input type="text" class="pad-top" id="{{id_op4}}"  
                   value="{{product_title4}}" readonly/><br></li>


      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Help me with this.
If you want any other information i will provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with `Polls_Coll.findOne()`. When you load the page, the data from database is not yet fetched, so all find queries are empty – therefore, `Polls_Coll.findOne(...)` returns undefined. Only later the helper is rerun and `findOne` returns the actual data.

The simplest solution is to check whether the data is in place:

```
Template.displayPoll.productTitle = function() {
  var poll = Polls_Coll.findOne(this._id);
  if(!poll) return '';
  return poll.option1[0].pd;
}
```